# Let G be a finite group. Let $a,b\in G$ be two distinct elements or order 2. Prove that if $ab=ba$, then the order of G is divisible by 4.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, divisible-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $a,b\in G$ be two distinct elements or order 2. Prove that if $ab=ba$, then the order of $G$ is divisible by 4.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: To prove that the order of $G$ is divisible by $4$, you simply need to show some subgroup of order $4$ exists (by Lagrange's theorem). Can you create such subgroup with what you know of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: I have tried to find an element whose square is a or b. But there's no guarantee such element exists in G.

Comment: No, there indeed isn't. But you don't need that either.

Answer (score 2):

$H=\{e,a,b,ab\}$ is a subgroup of $G$. By Lagrange's Theorem, $|H|$ divides $|G|$